# How to browse the client machine's logical drives, folders and subfolders in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How to browse the client machine's file system. Since it is not possible through c#, I've been trying through various resources like javascript and using activex control. Can someone help me in working out with how to get it done using either javascript or activex control.

Requirement:

My requirement is something like, when the client logs in, the code should be able to browse through the clients file system (drives, folders and subfolders) when he wants to navigate through. I need to display the file system in the form of treeview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this was possible I'd sue every browser manufacturer. Whoever came up with those requirements is either a criminal or high.

Comment: I'd either if the purpose is not according to the clients will.But when the situation demands and as per the requirement/willingness of the browser/user, that can be permitted.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried FileUpload Control? Hope so it will work for you to some extent.
Apart from this, no javascript or server side code can perform this action.

Comment: Yes, but through FileUpload control, we can only select files, that too a single file at a time. But my requirement is to select folder or even the entire drive in some situations, when the user wants to scan for certain files he needed.

Putting in simple terms, we just need online search functionality for a file when he navigates to a particular folder and enters a text and clicks on search button.